# RPi2B redlights when trying to boot into RaspBSD

Tags: pi-2, operating-systems, boot-issues, setup, freebsd

I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi 2 B to boot using [RaspBSD](http://raspbsd.org/). I had previously, and still can, boot into the latest Raspbian image.

After downloading and decompressing the RPi2 image from the RaspBSD site, I used

```
sudo dd if=FreeBSD-armv6-11.0-RPI2-291824.img of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m
```

To write it to a FAT32-formatted, 64GB MicroSD card.

After putting it into the MicroSD slot on the RPi, the board just lights up a solid red light for about a minute, before having that shut off too.

I've tried with another MicroSD card from a different brand, and the issue is persistent - but both cards work when trying to use Raspbian.

I've also noticed that the both lights on the ethernet socket do light up even after the red light shuts off, and the board shows up on my local network when running an `arp-scan`. SSHing does prompt for a password, but logging in with the default RaspBSD credentials always fails.

Am I missing any steps in getting RaspBSD to work on my Pi? If not, what should I do to get it up and running with BSD?

Comment: do you have any more information on this? i have the exact same problem.

Comment: I now had success logging in over the serial console via root/root. I used an FTDI usb to serial adapter (can be found online for under 5$). You need to connect RX, TX and GND. Here is an more in depth explanation that worked for me http://makezine.com/2014/02/28/talking-to-the-raspberry-pis-serial-console-with-an-ftdi-breakout-board/

Answer (score 2):

> After putting it into the MicroSD slot on the RPi, the board just lights up a solid red light for about a minute, before having that shut off too.

Something very odd is going on *or* you have an insufficient power supply.

If a Pi 2 does not recognize a card, it will power on with both the red PWR led and green ACT led lit solid and stay that way.  If it reads the card but has a problem with the firmware, bootloader, or kernel, the green led will blink in a noticeably regular pattern repeatedly.

Generally, having the red power LED go off is a bad sign, as in, physical damage (or insufficient power).  It is possible to run code to do so, however.  If it is intentional, that is a strange choice on behalf of the creators of RaspBSD.  I suppose there is some chance of it happening coincidentally, of course.

If the red light does not stay on steady when you are using Raspbian, *including after having halted/shutdown the system*, your Pi is damaged (or you have an insufficient power supply).  It should be on the entire time there is (sufficient) power attached.

Did I mention *insufficient power supply*? ;)

Comment: The green light does come on for a few seconds after powering it on with the RaspBSD card inserted, but both lights are on (with the ACT light flashing, but mostly on) when Raspbian's running -- and I've got no problems with Raspbian at all. I can do some pretty heavy combinatorics stuff in Python over SSH, with the CPU at full or near-full load, without issues.